# Android: How navigate to next screen after animation finish

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am trying to work on a feature that automatically navigates to the next screen after shows animation finished.

Comment: Provide what you have done so far .

Comment: I haven't done any yet. My idea is to create a base animation widget with on finish call back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of scale and alpha animation. You can do something like this:

```
view.animate()
  .scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f)//scale to half(half x,half y)
  .translationY((view.height/4).toFloat()).translationX((view.width/4).toFloat())// move to bottom / right
  .alpha(0.5f) // make it less visible
  .rotation(360f) // one round turns
  .setDuration(1000) // all take 1 seconds
  .withEndAction { 
    // Called on animation end
  }
```

Comment: Please mark it as an accepted answer if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of adding a callback after the animation ends.

```kotlin
view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000).withEndAction{
    startActivity(/** Your Intent */)
}
```

If this is not the case please provide more information about what type of animation you are using, and attach the sample code.